# jetpack compose material 3 CiricularProgressIndicator Doesnt spin at all on a physical device

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

Can someone help me understand this. I ran a simple project to test this with one screen and one circularprogressindcator at the center, the circularprogressindcator is indeterminate meaning is should spin forever. On the emulator is spins fine, however when i run the test on a physical device it wont spin the animation appears to be stuck. I'm not doing any heavy loading or block the UI thread. Not sure how to fix this or if this is a known bug, but would like some clarity on this. The physical device is a Samsung S10 plus which runs android 12 api level 31, not sure if this effects the component but just providing all the info I can. All dependency are up to date however i am using Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2. My compile SDk is 34,minSdk = 24 and targetSdk = 33  Here is the sample project code that I ran.

Main Activity

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            NavigationTestTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    AuthAScreen{}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Screen

```
@Composable
fun AuthAScreen(
    navigateToAuthB:() -> Unit
){
    Log.d("AuthAScreen", "AuthAScreen: Screen created ")

    Column(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        CircularProgressIndicator(
            modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            strokeWidth = 4.dp,
            /* other optional properties */
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, which version of Jetpack Compose is used for the project? I've tested the provided code both on an emulator (Pixel 3a - API 27) and a physical device (Galaxy A52 - API 33), with compose version 1.5.4 and the progress indicator spins fine. Is there any chance your physical device's animations are turned off from the Developer Settings?

Comment: wow you are correct, my animations on the device were off. Thank you so much I've been trying to figure out this problem for a while now. I was concerned it would affect the app. I will do my research on developer setting so that a situation like this doesn't happen. again thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As referred by @stoyan_vuchev and for other people who might come across this issue, you should change animation settings in developer options in emulator/physical device.

Under DRAWING section set all animation scale to 1x.

also emulator can -for some random reasons, or battery saving- turn animation off, so if your animation doesn't work check these options.

this issue is not exclusive for compose loaders in xml stops to show too

[image]